# Symfony form autocomplete with entity relationship

Tags: ajax, forms, doctrine

I'm using Syfmony 2.8

I have 2 entities:

Cities with list of city in country: id, name, district etc.

and

Workers: id, id_city, name, surname

Cities an Workers have 1 to many relationship

When creating a new worker i can't display all of Cities because number of cities are over 100k. I need to have autocompletion with ajax (I'm guessing) but how can I show in form "Name" of city and "district" and set in worker id_city id of selected city?

Example:
User type "Abi"
Suggested cities:
Abisynia (region 4)
Abisynia (region 8)
User select Abisynia with region 4 which have id: 413 and i need to create relationship with this id :)

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make it with ajax and query with a Like statement.

Only trigger the ajax call when user types more than n characters and make a delay with javascript, so you don't query the database for every character typed.